# Cellular internet coverage in the Pyrenees

Tags: cellphones, spain, internet, data-plans, pyrenees

I'm looking to buy a SIM card with a data plan. What company has coverage in the Pyrenees?

Any recommendation for a plan with 3G coverage there?

Comment: Andorra? France? Spain?

Comment: He originally tagged it as Spain, so can probably assume that for now...

Comment: Spanish Pyrenees indeed.

Answer (score 3):

I used Vodafone (they had 3G) and it worked fine in Spain. Once I made it to Andorra, I was roaming and was told what the charges would be.  I assume it would be the same had I continued on to France.
The rate was 10 EUR for unlimited Internet which cost something like 3.15 EUR per week. They credited the full 10EUR to your account.  Once I hit 20MB/day, it throttled me, but I could still access the Internet.  I also had phone as well as texting.

Just stop at a Vodafone place anywhere in Spain.  I was in Spain for almost two weeks and I had Internet the whole time without any issues.

There is also Movistar, but I don't know if they had 3G.  They had 20 EUR for 500MB of data.

Comment: Indeed, information about roaming charges is mandatory under EU law and the price is capped so it should be very similar in France and many other countries.